# how to make the graph click able in android?

Tags: android

I got one good example for piechart in android.
http://blog.gafmediastudio.com/2010/04/01/draw-a-pie-chart-with-android/
I am trying to make the graph clickable and show some details of the particular sector/pie which was clicked by the user. Please can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like PieChart extends a View. If you look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), they give you all the methods you need to override to handle click events.